# Event triggerred but not all the code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

i am working on a project on github named [lan-info](https://github.com/TheLinuxPro/lan-info/). 
i have the following code

```
let arpSweepCommand = './arpSweep.sh';
app.get('/arp', (req, res) => {
  console.log('we have a working signal!');
  executeCommand(arpSweepCommand, req, res, false);
  fs.readFile('command_output/arpedHosts.txt', 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
    } else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  })
})
```

and arpSweep.sh contains:

```
timeout 10s netdiscover -P > command_output/arpedHosts.txt
```

and in my frontend i have a Jquery AJAX call:

```
arpButton.click(function () {
  loader.show();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/arp',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      commandOutput.append(data);
      loader.hide();
    }
  })
})
```

i know that there are no syntactical errors because webpack compiles the frontend code without complaints; and i know that the backend does catch the request as whenever i click `arpButton` it prints 'we have a signal!' on the server. 
but the problem is loader.show()/hide() seem to do nothing in only this ajax request i know that this is specific to this ajax request because i have similar requests that function perfectly. 
the problem for me is the information isn't automatically appended to `commandOutput`. 
i need to reclick `arpButton` another time for the output to be appended to `commandOutput`. 
but the loader wont show up for me i know that the loader isn't appearing and disappearing very fast because the ajax call takes at least 10 seconds to complete. 
the other problem is the data doesn't appear automatically after 10 seconds in `commandOutput` i tested that only the loader is malfunctioning by waiting for 30 minutes after clicking `arpButton` but nothing happens; when i proceed to click `arpButton` again the output is shown instantly. 
so why isnt the page updating itself? it instead forces me to reclick the button.
if you need more information you can click the project link above the files are: 
src/index.js 
index.js 
arpSweep.sh 
NOTE: be sure to change the subnet in the top of index.js if its not the subnet you use (automatic subnet detection is a feature i plan on implementing later). 
EDIT: after trying to read the file as a callback for `executeCommand`:

```
function executeCommand (command, req, res, sendRes = true, callback) {
  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`)
    } else if (sendRes === false) {
    } else if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback()
    } else {
      res.send(stdout + stderr)
    }
  })
}
app.get('/arp', (req, res) => {
  console.log('we have a working signal!')
  executeCommand(arpSweepCommand, req, res, false, function () {
    fs.readFile('command_output/arpedHosts.txt', 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
      if (error !== null) {
        res.send(error)
      } else {
        res.send(data)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

i am encountering a new problem: 
when `arpButton` is clicked now the loader shows up but after 10 seconds (the time allocated to the command in arpSweep.sh before netdiscover is killed) seems to make no difference and the loader seems to stay there forever now. 
and on the server i am catching the following error.

```
error: Error can't execute command './arpSweep.sh'
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get your problem and need more information to help, e.g. what do you mean with "Isn't this the purpose of ajax" in connection with "automatically append"? Your `success` method will be called when the execution finishes on the server and data is returned so that's exactly what you seem to find wrong as stated in your second last sentence. Clicking the button twice may seem as if this solves the problem but in fact it may be like this: `click button > script starts and takes 10 seconds > click again > script triggered by first click finishes and returns`.

Comment: Tried your project locally and what can I say - everything ok with the loader, the thing that when you sending `ping` with empty string - loader shows and not hides because it never succeed (500 error) and when you doing `arp` - loader shows and hides almost immediately because it gets 200 OK in about 5ms. So if you want the loader to persist while some work on the server is in progress - you should not return the response immediately.

Comment: @SaschaM78 but if that's the case why doesn't the loader show up indicating that serverside code is under execution

Answer (score 0):

> the problem for me is the information isn't automatically appended to `commandOutput`

The issue you have is because the browser doesn't know how to `append` `json` (I assume it is not always json response).
Try to append `responseText` instead of `data`:

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
  console.log(data)
  commandOutput.append(xhr.responseText + '\r\n')
}
```

As of loader - everything OK with it, maybe you just need to hide it not on `success`, but on `complete` callback.

In this part:

```
executeCommand(arpSweepCommand, req, res, false)
fs.readFile('command_output/arpedHosts.txt', 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
```

You calling executeCommand asynchronously, so you can't be sure that the output is from the current call (that is probably the core of the issue when you need to click twice). So you should move `reading file` part of the code inside of the `exec` callback inside of the `executeCommand` method like this:

```
function executeCommand (command, req, res, cb) {
  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`)
    } else {
      if (typeof cb === 'function') {
        cb()
      } else {
        res.send(stdout + stderr)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
executeCommand(arpSweepCommand, req, res, () => {
  fs.readFile('command_output/arpedHosts.txt', 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send(error)
    } else {
      res.send(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: but doesn't res.send() always return text and doesn't putting a lot of things in one function violate the idea of having a function only do one 'thing'?

Comment: > `always return text` - indeed, with image response it won't work. With any text-based it will work (json and xml as well).
> `doesn't putting a lot of things in one function violate the idea of having a function only do one 'thing'`?

The function still does one thing and then calls callback which is passed as a parameter. Each function here does one thing.

Comment: so `callback != function_responsability`?

Comment: @TheLinuxPro correct. This is chaining approach and certain function does not do all that code included into callback, it just calls callback on the end of execution (or when it is should be called)

Comment: where can i learn more about this concept i never really understood callbacks

Comment: Well, this is the basic approach of javascript. For some places, async/await/Promises looks cleaner and clearer, but for such cases, there is no real difference. So for you here any case should work which will solve the asynchronous code. Consider accepting any answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `executeCommand` is asynchronous (it uses `child_process.exec`), so you are reading the file content BEFORE has been written, and that's why you need to click the button again to see the content in the next request. See the example here and how to make it sync-like with `promisify` and `async/await`: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Something like this (not tested):

```js
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function executeCommand (command, req, res, sendRes = true) {
  return exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`)
    } else if (sendRes === false) {
    } else {
      res.send(stdout + stderr)
    }
  })
}
```

and then, in your handler:

```js
await executeCommand(arpSweepCommand, req, res, false);
```

Comment: doesn't an extra library like promisify add bloat though? and didn't async/await supposedly fix the problem's related to callback hell and promises being complex?

Comment: and i was trying to get rid of jquery you tell me 'get promisify' lol

Comment: promisify comes from the standard `util` library in node js, you don't need any extra library, and `exec` DOES uses callbacks, that why I suggest flatten your code by using promises and aync/await, much more readable IMHO...
and yes, please get rid of jquery... in your front end :)